# Poisson approximation of a binomial model with random effects - how to get robust variance estimates

Tags: binary-data, random-effects-model, poisson-regression, robust-standard-error

I'm interested in using a Poisson approximation for modeling a common (~40% of the time) binary outcome. But my data has some clustering in it, having come from three different sites, which suggests the use of a random effects model.

Getting the actual estimates are easy enough, using something like lme4 in R:

```
model <- glmer(Outcome ~ Sex + Age + (1|Site), data=study, family=poisson)
```

The problem is that Zou G. A modified Poisson regression approach to prospective
studies with binary data. Am J Epidemiol. 2004;159(7):702–706 suggests that a robust variance estimator is needed using this method, but the standard `sandwich` library doesn't work (by, as I understand it, design) with lme4.

Which suggests two questions:

1. Is a robust variance estimator still needed in this circumstance?
2. How does one obtain one?

Answer (score 1):

I would model the sites as fixed effects: you should have the power to do so and it theoretically achieves the same effect as including a random effect. Adjusting for site as either a fixed or random effect makes participants within the same site *conditionally independent* of each other. The random effects variance estimates becomes a little unwieldy when nearly 50% of the off-diagonal covariance matrix entries are non-zero.

If the model has entirely fixed effects it is amenable to estimation with a GEE and that solves the problem easily.

If you had more sites, another approach would be using the robust sandwich- variance estimate to the generalized least squares model using an exchangeable correlation structure for site-based clusters. [Random intercepts and exchangeable correlation lead to equivalent estimates when the intracluster correlation is positive](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209480/what-if-anything-is-the-relationship-between-random-intercepts-models-and-comp) and that's usually the case. Sandwich-variance calculation can be done by-hand [as shown here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331840/how-to-calculate-sandwich-standard-errors-for-generalized-least-squares-models).